# How would I unit test a method that uses a nuget package?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class library which has a `MyService` class which implements the `IMyService` interface. This contains 2 methods, `AuthorizationLogin()` and `ExchangeCodeForToken()`.

The first one just calls a method in the nuget package, let's call it `MyClient`

```
public string AuthorizationLogin()
{
    return _myClient.BuildUri();
}
```

Then the second one just takes the returned `code` a requests an access token

```
public async Task ExhangeCodeForToken(
    string code)
{
    var token = await _myClient.RequestTokenAsync(code);

    MyAccounts myAccount = new()
    {
        AccessToken = token.AccessToken,
        RefreshToken = token.RefreshToken,
        Scopes = _configuration["MyClient:Scopes"]
    };

    _myAccountsRepository.AddAccount(myAccount);

}
```

How would I go about writing tests for these methods? What sorts of things should I be testing for? Should I be unit testing (maybe not) or integration testing?

Comment: you should create a mock for your client probably that does *not* use the package. Depending on where you create the client and the sort of mocking-framrwork you can easily replace the one by the other.

Answer (score 0):

You should write unit and integration for `AuthorizationLogin()` and `ExchangeCodeForToken()` respectively.

Unit test for `AuthorizationLogin()` because it simply calls a method from class of `_myClient`, unit test will make sure it's calling `BuildUri()` correctly.

Integration test for `ExchangeCodeForToken()` because it has external dependancies. You should make sure,  this method correctly handles the token received and then it is correctly interacts with your repository `_myAccountsRepository`

You will have to mock interface of `MyClient` and interface of `_myAccountsRepository`'s class.

You might like to test following,

- Success and failure scenarios for both methods.
- Exception handling for example - what happens when `RequestTokenAsync()` returns null.
- Verify `AddAccount()` is called successfully with expected parameters.